# liip imagine bundle creating thumbnails that are all the same file size

Tags: php, symfony, thumbnails, liipimaginebundle

We are using Symfony2 and the LiipImagineBundle to create thumbnails of user uploaded content.

Every thumbnail is exactly 161kb, no matter how much or how little it has in the image.

Here is my config file for liip:

```
liip_imagine:
    resolvers:
        default:
            web_path: ~
    filter_sets:
        my_thumb:
            quality: 75
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [80, 80], mode: outbound }
        productvariant_preview:
            filters:
                resize: { size: [450, 450] }
        productvariant_thumb:
            filters:
                resize: { size: [292, 292] }
        productvariantdesign_thumb:
            filters:
                resize: { size: [231, 231] }
        profiledesign_thumb:
            filters:
                resize: { size: [200, 200] }
        asseenindesign_thumb:
            filters:
                resize: { size: [158, 158] }
        homepage_slider:
            filters:
                resize: { size: [922, 388] }
        homepage_featuredlink:
            filters:
                resize: { size: [450, 260] }
        homepage_secondaryfeaturedlink:
            filters:
                resize: { size: [294, 188] }
        homepage_productvariantdesign:
            filters:
                resize: { size: [223, 223] }
        printcolor_thumbnail:
            filters:
                resize: { size: [30, 30] }
```

Resize Filter:

```
namespace Imagine\Filter\Basic;

use Imagine\Filter\FilterInterface;
use Imagine\Image\ImageInterface;
use Imagine\Image\BoxInterface;

/**
 * A resize filter
 */
class Resize implements FilterInterface
{   
    /**
     * @var BoxInterface
     */
private $size;
private $filter;

/**
 * Constructs Resize filter with given width and height
 *
 * @param BoxInterface $size
 * @param string       $filter
 */
public function __construct(BoxInterface $size, $filter = ImageInterface::FILTER_UNDEFINED)
{
    $this->size = $size;
    $this->filter = $filter;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function apply(ImageInterface $image)
{
    return $image->resize($this->size, $this->filter);
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of filter is "resize" ? It is not mentioned in official documentation - there is only relative_resize filter (http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/LiipImagineBundle/filters.html)?

Comment: I added the code for the filter in the question.

Comment: @Jeremy, that's not what Miro is talking about. The built in filter for relative resize is called `relative_resize` and not `resize`

Answer (score 1):

I don't 100% know what was happening but adding

driver: imagick

fixed the issue.